# System not Booting into Ubuntu 22.04.3 After Creating Swap Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, swap, grub-efi

I was trying to create a swap partition on my Ubuntu 23.04.3 which eventually worked out just fine, but after powering off the system and powering it back on a few times after use, I discovered I couldn't boot into my OS. It boots into the grub terminal after displaying an error message that says `/boot not found.`

After trying a few workarounds which all didn't work, I tried using a live USB option. This seemed to work well until I encountered this error when using boot-repair:

```
Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 22.04.
```

Here's what I got when I tried generating a Bootinfo summary of what boot-repair detected: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dqCTnd6PtX/.

I would sincerely appreciate any help as I have a lot of important files on that drive and I've got an assignment to submit in two days time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a usb-stick with a 'super_grub2_disk_hybrid_' iso (https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). You can use an old stick you have as it is a very small .iso ( around 20 MiB ). When starting up/booting this stick it will scan all the bootable systems you have on your system. Then boot into 'Ubuntu' and do a grub update ( when booted in Ubuntu open a terminal (press Ctrl + Alt + T at the same time), in the terminal type sudo update-grub , wait for the update to finish). Or you can boot your Ubuntu installation/live stick if you still have this.

Then you have to change your 'Fstab'-file ( as root ). You can do this in the terminal with 'gedit' or 'nano'. You find this file in the 'etc'-folder. You need to add the swap-partition. The best way is to know the UUID of the partition ( use 'GParted' ( right click on the partition and choose 'information' or use 'blkid' (in terminal) ). Write down the numbers of all the partitions. In 'Fstab' add the partition like this: [image: fstab with swap] 
  Also make sure that the UUID of the boot and the root ('/') are correct. Save the changes.